# AWS Appflow Incremental Schedule Flows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-appflow

Considering that IncrememntalPullConfig in AWS AppFlow config is optional, if IncrementalPullConfig is not provided with a value in an Incremental AppFlow scheduled to pull data from Salesforce, how does AppFlow fetch the changes from Salesforce? What field does it use and how is that field determined?

Thanks.

Trying to get the data for LoginHistory Object from Salesforce into S3 through On Scheduled Appflow job, however, it is failing with the below error.

The request failed because the service Source Salesforce returned the following error: Details: [{"message":"\ncount() from LoginHistory where SystemModstamp < 2024-02-23T11:48:09.651Z\n ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:40\nNo such column 'SystemModstamp' on entity 'LoginHistory'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}], StatusCode: 400., RequestId: bddb78aac2233fb690237115334f23a2